# Are "href's" the proper way to switch pages within a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

So I've been using the old fashioned way to switch between pages within my websites, I *include my header on every page* and use a/href's to go to another page.. I only use ajax requests within the pages themselves only. Not to switch my visitors to another page, as I said, I do that with native href's.

I looked at the history.pushState() to change the url's on the address bar every time I load a new page via jquery ajax. And it does it pretty well. The thing is when I refresh the page, it does keep the same url and loads that url/file again. But the file comes back nude, with no CSS and no header, since those are only included in my index.

I use php as my SS though.

Any good advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hrefs is perfectly fine, and standard. However, there are some performance gains to be had by avoiding full page loads via ajax.

If you *do* want to use pushState and ajax you have to configure your server so that all HTTP requests hit your index page/router. You can do this in nginx, apache, express js, or whatever you're using on the backend.

Then in your JS you'll want to sniff `window.location` to see what page the user is currently at and fire an ajax request immediately to load that page.

Alternatively, a faster but more difficult approach is to *not* set your server to point all requests to your index, and *actually* serve the full HTML for the page they request (HTML, CSS, headers and footers) so that the page doesn't come back "nude". This will make the initial page load faster. After that, you can resume using ajax requests as they navigate around the site.

How you do this depends on your technology stack. If you're using webpack like me, then at least in dev-mode you can set `historyApiFallback: true` to have all requests "fallback" to your index, and then I'm using React Router to load the appropriate page. But again, you might be using something different.

Comment: Both methods sound great, thanks. Although I prefer the second one since it'll be easier to load everything on every file to prevent my page to come back nude (meaning only html, and no css or js), but that way I will need to include my css files on every single page of my sites and it will be to heavy to load over and over again every time a visitor clicks an option in the menu don't you think?

Comment: @Ed91gg That's the hard part. You have to serve the full page when they load it fresh, and then only load the parts that change with AJAX as they navigate around. You have to make your content modular so that you can do this effectively. Ideally (IMO), you would only transfer some JSON data as they navigate around, and render your templates with JS.

Comment: thank you, I'm on that ATM and seems like a nice approach to achieve it. and I was already transfering JSON's here and there, my only issue was on deciding a better way to switch withing the site pages instead of realoding the whole page for every click someone makes in any option from the menu. Thanks you! Any other advice will always be appreciated.